# Best and most efficient format for variable degree of freedom force vectors for linear algebra?

Tags: arrays, enums, rust

I'm working with force vectors of *up to* six degrees of freedom, representing (Fx, Fy, Fz, Mx, My, Mz). Depending on the desired use, I will regularly only need three degrees of freedom, i.e. (Fx, Fy, Mz).

My first instinct is to use fixed length `ndarray::Array1`s of size `(6,)` though that will mean carrying around extra zeroes most of the time. It seems clear that would be the easiest in terms of implementing all of the math. But without further reduction it will lead to performing linear algebra using full 6x6 mass matrices that are half empty. Is there any chance that an `enum` could offer some efficiency in this respect? Such as:

```
pub enum ForceArr<F64> {
    ThreeDOF([f64; 3]),
    FourDOF([f64; 4]),
    FiveDOF([f64; 5]),
    SixDOF([f64; 6]),
}
```

Which would need to be converted to `array1`s before performing more complex operations. Or:

```
use ndarray::Array1;

pub enum ForceArray<F64> {
    ThreeDOF(Array1<f64>),
    FourDOF(Array1<f64>),
    FiveDOF(Array1<f64>),
    SixDOF(Array1<f64>),
}
```

Though I can't figure out how to enforce the size of the different arrays in that second option, so I assume it would be less efficient. I know enums are sized as the size of their largest element plus a discriminator

My other thought was an enum explicitly enumerating the indices of the full 6DOF array to take in order to get reduced views of vectors/matrices, such as:

```
pub enum ForceIdxs<U8> {
    ThreeDOF([u8; 3]) = [0, 1, 5],
    FourDOF([u8; 4]) = [0, 1, 3, 5],
    FiveDOF([u8; 5]) = [0, 1, 3, 4, 5],
    SixDOF([u8; 6]) = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
}
```

But that is still experimental: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60553. Though it would work with my initial plan of `Array1`s of size `(6,)` and allow reducing force vectors and mass matrices by indexing to simplify the complexity of linear algebra operations to be performed.

I could also set up each function to just handle that indexing operation manually, which is starting to seem like the 'best of both worlds' option...

Answer (score 0):

I found the `nalgebra` crate as possibly the best solution. It has a full set of `Vector3` through `Vector6` and equivalent `Matrix3` to `Matrix6` structs so I can maintain granular control. Plus it does not require OpenBLAS/Netlib/IntelMKL!